# Passing extra arguments to networkx graphviz_layout not working

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I want to pass an extra argument to the `graphviz_layout()`, which I am doing, but it's not doing anything. I have also tried passing other arguments, but same problem.

It is correctly recognizing it, because if I change the argument I pass to something nonsensical I get an error.

I am referring to this documentation: [https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:len)

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

G = model.block_tree.tree
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', root=0, args='-Grankdir="LR"')

plt.title(r"Blockchain with Selfish Mining ($\alpha$ = {})".format(alpha))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=color_vector, node_shape='s', node_size=300)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10, font_color="white")
plt.show()
```

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?

This is the graph that I am producing. I would expect it to rotate, so that it is horizontal, but it's not...

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why? I'd be super grateful. Thanks in advance!

PS: There are some related posts, but none worked for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a conflict between the rankdir argument you're providing and the 'root' argument. If you remove the latter, it should respect your ordering.

Because I don't have your data, I made a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from([0, 1])
G.add_edge(0, 1)
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', root=0, args='-Grankdir="LR"')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_shape='s', node_size=300)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges(), arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10, font_color="white")
plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

But if I just remove the `root=0` argument, I get:

[image]

Comment: Halleluja! This solved my problem immediately. Thanks you!